Asymptotic expansion of Hankel transform of even function
I have found in this paper that the integral
$$
I(k) = \int^{\infty}_0 f(x) J_0(kx)x \,dx \tag{9}
$$
has a closed formula for the asymptotic expansion in $k$. The problem is that this doesn't work if $f$ is an even function, as stated in condition 1 of Theorem 1 (page 4).
My question is then if there exist a similar expression that allows me to expand/approximate (9) when $f(x)$ is even. In particular, I am interested in calculating (9) for
$$
f_c(x) = \dfrac{\cos{\omega \sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}} \quad\text{and}\quad f_s(x) = \dfrac{\sin{\omega \sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}},
$$
where $a>0$.

Have you tried https://doi.org/10.1016/0898-1221(77)90084-0 ?
